# How to add customization in toast

Tags: smali

## virtual methods

.method public run()V

```
.registers 5

.prologue

.line 633

:try_start_0

invoke-static {}, Landroid/ext/ToastManager;->getContext()Landroid/content/Context;

move-result-object v2

iget-object v1, p0, Landroid/ext/Tools$11;->val$text:Ljava/lang/String;

if-nez v1, :cond_18

const-string v1, "null"

:goto_a

invoke-static {v1}, Landroid/ext/Re;->s(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v1

iget v3, p0, Landroid/ext/Tools$11;->val$time:I

invoke-static {v2, v1, v3}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

move-result-object v1

invoke-virtual {v1}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V

.line 637

:goto_17

return-void

.line 633

:cond_18

iget-object v1, p0, Landroid/ext/Tools$11;->val$text:Ljava/lang/String;

:try_end_1a

.catch Ljava/lang/Throwable; {:try_start_0 .. :try_end_1a} :catch_1b

goto :goto_a

.line 634

:catch_1b

move-exception v0

.line 635

.local v0, "e":Ljava/lang/Throwable;

const-string v1, "Toast fail"

invoke-static {v1, v0}, Landroid/ext/Log;->w(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)I

goto :goto_17
```

.end method

I want to add customization for toast but nothing works for me, the application crashes, I need to add gradient background color, padding, stroke, stroke size, stroke color.

I tried to add it myself but the application crashes when toast appears

Comment: Start in Android Studio a new Java based app, add a new method to the main activity, add your code for showing and customizing the toast, build the APK and decompile the apk to smali, then you will get the code you need and only have to make minor adaptions.